# JQuery SetAttribute of Input Field on Key Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a attribute of Input field if user Enters some characters in to the text/check box. Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sirishkumar/dFBzW/51/) to Java Script I am trying. Below is the code

```
<input type="text" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

```
$('input').bind('input keyup', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val());
    $(this).setAttribute('aria-invalid', 'true');
});
```

But it is not working, can someone guide me?

Comment: Instead of using non-standard attributes, go for the `data-*` attribute

Comment: @roXon They're not non-standard: http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/

Comment: As a minor aside, you can - and should - use `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()` to access the value of the element triggering the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a jQuery object and the actual DOM node. In that event handler, `this` is the DOM node, and `$(this)` is a jQuery object that references it.

The DOM node itself has the `setAttribute` function, the jQuery object has the `.attr()` function, so:

```
this.setAttribute('aria-invalid', 'true');
or
$(this).attr('aria-invalid', 'true');
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eteleg/1/edit)**</kbd>

Try using `data` attribute instead with the `.data()` method. It's quite easy:

```
$('input').on('input keyup', function() {
    $('#output').html( this.value );
    $(this).data('aria_invalid', 'true');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object does not have a `.setAttribute()` method. Use the .attr() method of the JQuery (or the Dom Element .setAttribute() method)

```
$('input').bind('input keyup', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val());

    $(this).attr('aria-invalid', 'true');
    // or
    // this.setAttribute('aria-invalid', 'true');
});
```